# Can't add file with httpClient with C# and get it with nodejs and multer

Tags: c#, node.js, dotnet-httpclient

I am using a server with nodejs and writing file with multer. While using with kotlin I can easily send file with the following code with retrofit:

```
val reqFile: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.name, reqFile)
val name = "upload".toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaTypeOrNull())
//val token = ...token

val message = messageToUpload
    .toRequestBody("text/plain; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())

val req: Call<ResponseBody?>? =
    apiService!!.postImage("Bearer $token", name, message, body)

Log.d("Tag", "uploading file...")
```

multer middleware usage code:

```
router.post(
  "/upload",
  isValidUser,
  multer({
    storage: storage,
  }).single("upload"),
  async function (req, res) { //... 
   }

// Include the node file module
var fs = require("fs");

storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads/",
  filename: async function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
```

However I am unsuccessful on sending file with `httpClient` with C#. I do not have enough knowledge with this. So I need suggestion of its usage to make the file written in my server, just like it does with kotlin retrofit requests.Maybe I am sending the wrong name. But all time I get file is undefined, while I access `const fileName = req.file.filename;`

Here is the code with C#:

```
 string fullFilePath = @"C:\image.jpg";
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath);

                    using var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                    //add file part
                    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullFilePath))
                    {
                        using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs))
                        {
                            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
                            fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"");
                            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
                            requestContent.Add(fileContent, "upload", fileName);

                            var response1 = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:3000/api/upload"), requestContent).Result;
                            string result = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                            Console.WriteLine(result);

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: I dont have enough knowledge with httpClient. I can add files and texts I thought. Should I do just add a form data and add file content to it? I need to know why the `req.file` is undefined and a solve to it the most.

Comment: Why are you declaring that the byte data is multipart form data, when it isn't? It's an image. You certainly don't need the `Content-Disposition` header, as `requestContent.Add` is already taking care of that part for you. And the `Content-Type` header for the file content should clearly be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted and rewrote my comment with more info.

Comment: I don't know why it's undefined. It may be because your double Content-Disposition is confusing it.

Comment: Please dont focus on image only. I can send multiple images or an other file such as a .pdf file. Thanks for your comment, I will try it.

Comment: The file is actually available in the body and I dont know how to access / extract it with multer.